# Use EOMONTH in my VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble using EOMONTH in this piece of VBA code:

```
'Create a new file that will receive the data
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
With newWB

        Set newS = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        newS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'Save in CSV

      Dim PathDate    As String
      Dim SavePath    As String
      Dim SaveAs      As String
      Dim FileName    As String
      Dim sDate       As String

'// File path date
PathDate = Format(Range("D1"), 0), "MMDDYYYY")

'// Save it Path
SavePath = "C:\User"

'// Format the on "D1" to MMDDYYYY
sDate = Format(currentWB.Sheets("Upload sheet").Range("D1"), "MM.DD.YYYY")

'// File Name
FileName = "NewFileName"

'// Save with File Name & Date & .CSV
SaveAs = SavePath & "\" & FileName & "-" & sDate & ".csv"
.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
```

All I want to do is have the same outcome that =EOMONTH(D1,0) would give me, instead of where it says S2.

Comment: Did you try `Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth()`?

Comment: Yes, and it has an error pop up saying "Compile Error:  Argument not optional"

Comment: please show how you tried to use it, it will help us help you.

Comment: Just added context

Comment: `sDate = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(currentWB.Sheets("Upload sheet").Range("D1"),0), "MM.DD.YYYY")` should do it for you  make sure you declare `sDate as string`

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
PathDate = Format(currentWB.Sheets("Upload sheet").Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("D1").value, 0)), "MMDDYYYY")
```

You said in place of S2. I am wondering if that is a little too literal and you mean

```
With currentWB.Sheets("Upload sheet")
     PathDate = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(.Range("D1").value, 0),"MMDDYYYY")
End With
```

Comment: This one gives a runtime error "Unable to get the EoMonth property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: With the .Value ?

Comment: I'm just referring to where it says S2 in the line of code

Comment: I am saying did you run with Range("D1").value in the code? As @ScottCraner has pointed out, it would help to see how you are trying to apply this.

Comment: Note this implicitly uses the ActiveSheet